# Show all post types in the same table of posts

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-list-table

I wonder if there is any way to show all post types in the same table of posts.

Let's say I've got 3 different post types: Movies, Books and Videogames.

Is there any way to show them all in a single table of posts?

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course, if you set the query argument 'post_type' to 'any', it will retrieve any type except revisions and types with 'exclude_from_search' set to true.

Example:

`$all_posts = get_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'any' ) );`

Otherwise, if you don't want ALL post types, just certain ones:

`$specific_posts = get_posts( array( 'post_type' => array( 'movies', 'books', 'videogames' ) ) );`

Source: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Parameters